# Why is my object not being populated from a GET request with C# RestSharp?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, restsharp

I'm retrieving an object from a REST API GET call with RestSharp like so:

```
        var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:8800");
        var request = new RestRequest("api/users/{id}", Method.GET);
        request.AddUrlSegment("id", "9");

        IRestResponse<User> response = client.Execute<User>(request);
        User user = response.Data;
```

The `User` object is totally unpopulated, even though the GET request is returning a fully populated value (the REST API is running in another instance of Visual Studio and I watched the response).

My parameterless default constructor does no work, but all of the parameters are publicly accessible.  Why is RestSharp not populating my `User` object?

Comment: Can you capture the response (and its headers), for example using Fiddler, and place it in your question, as well as the `User` class? Is `null` returned, an default/empty `User` instance or an exception?

Comment: @CodeCaster Sure, I'll grab that.  In the mean time, it's returning an empty object, as in its non-null, but the values for all attributes are all the default values.  It's definitely a serializable object, since I can call the GET interface through the browser and get a fully populated event.

Comment: @CodeCaster Odd. I set a breakpoint in the REST API Server code, it gets called and returns the right value, but Fiddler isn't picking up any HTTP requests.